# Is there a way to get SWIFT automation to work with external API's?

Tags: iphone, swift, automation, automated-tests, external-application

I am working on an application that connects with the external API of iOS contacts. When using SWIFT automation record button, it thinks that it finds the button, but, when the code runs the automation it is not able to locate elements within the Contact API. What code do I need to add in order to be able to have swift interact with external application?
Side note, the application also access Apple Maps and it is not able to return to the application is there a way around that too?

Answer (score -1):

In general, Swift automated testing is quite buggy and has a lot of problems interacting with 3rd party elements when you go to record them. It would, however, be helpful to see the output in Swift from when you record this particular button.

Comment: When I user the "Recored" option within Xcode is does not generate an output. Could you be more detailed about what output you are talking about? or is there a setting within Xcode to show the output when recording?